# Indy upload speed

Tags: delphi, indy

From this code, how can I return the upload speed?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

ftp.Host := 'domain';
ftp.Username := 'username';
ftp.password := 'password';
ftp.Connect;
ftp.Put('random-filename.ext'); //This is where it should grab only the latest file
//label1.caption := 'Download Speed: %s';  
ftp.Quit;
ftp.Disconnect;

end;
```

Would a timer be necessary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using a `TIdFTP` component then you must use the `OnWork`, `OnWorkBegin` and `OnWorkEnd` events to calculate the transfer rate.

Answer (score 2):

The `TIdFTP.OnWorkBegin` event will tell you how many bytes are going to be sent, and the `TIdFTP.OnWork` event will tell you how many bytes have been sent so far during the transfer. Based on how much time passes between individual `OnWork` event firings and the difference in transferred bytes between each one, you can calculate the speed.

Answer (score 1):

No TTimer class is necessary, only Indy component OnWorkBegin, OnWork and OnWorkEnd events.

You can do like below but I recommend you to put FTP code in a thread and to update user interface with the Synchronize method for best performance.

```
interface 

uses
  // ...
  Windows;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    startWriteTime : DWord;
    byteToWrite : Int64;

    procedure ftp_OnWorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCountMax: Int64);
    procedure ftp_OnWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
    procedure ftp_OnWorkEnd(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);

    procedure displayWriteSpeed(byteWritten: Int64);
end;

implementation

uses
  // ...
  SysUtils;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ftp.OnWorkBegin := ftp_OnWorkBegin;
  ftp.OnWork := ftp_OnWork;
  ftp.OnWorkEnd := ftp_OnWorkEnd;
  // ...
  ftp.Connect;
  // ...
end;

procedure TForm1.ftp_OnWorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCountMax: Int64);
begin
  if AWorkMode = wmWrite then
  begin
    byteToWrite := AWorkCountMax;
    startWriteTime := Windows.GetTickCount;
    displayWriteSpeed(-1);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ftp_OnWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
begin
  if AWorkMode = wmWrite then
  begin
    displayWriteSpeed(AWorkCount);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ftp_OnWorkEnd(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
begin
  if AWorkMode = wmWrite then
  begin
    displayWriteSpeed(byteToWrite);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.displayWriteSpeed(byteWritten: Int64);
var
  elapsedMilliSeconds,  elapsedSeconds : Dword;
  speedBytesPerSeconds : Int64;
begin
  if byteWritten < 0 then
  begin
    {writeSpeedLabel.}Caption := 'upload speed: ?';
    Exit;
  end;

  elapsedMilliSeconds := Windows.GetTickCount - startWriteTime;
  elapsedSeconds := elapsedMilliSeconds div 1000;
  speedBytesPerSeconds := byteWritten div elapsedSeconds;
  {writeSpeedLabel.}Caption := SysUtils.Format('upload speed: %d b/s', [speedBytesPerSeconds ] );
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the timer part:

You can use the built in functions and global variables:

```
var
  start, stop, elapsed: TDateTime;
  ielapsed: Integer;

// Start the timer
start := Now;
// Stop the timer
stop := Now;
elapsed := stop - start;
// Convert to milliseconds
ielapsed := round(elapsed * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000);
```

Since the Windows API function [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408.aspx) is already in milliseconds, it's an easy way to calculate elapsed time, but only on Windows 2000+:

```
var
  start, stop, elapsed: DWORD;

start := GetTickCount;
stop := GetTickCount;

if (stop > start) then
begin
  elapsed := stop - start;
end
else
begin
  // Handle overflow
  elapsed := MAXDWORD - start + stop;
end;
```